# How to use generate multiple of something with a single function using vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript

In the snippet below, I'm generating a single math problem on load, and if the **New Problem** button is clicked, the problem will refresh with a new one.

I want 3 problems to be able to display on the page. In pseudo code, this would be:

`forEach class called .problem, display a different math problem`.

This is what I have thus far, but I'm not getting the result I need.

```js
let getAddition = () => {
  let max = 10;
  let rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
  let rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
  let sum = rand1 + rand2;
  let problems = document.querySelectorAll('.problems');
  
  problems.forEach((problem) => {
    problem.textContent = `${rand1} + ${rand2} = ${sum}`;
  });
};

window.addEventListener('onload', getAddition());
newProblem.onclick = () => {
  getAddition();
};
```

```html
<button type="button" id="newProblem">New Problem</button>
<div class="container">
  <div class="problem"></div>
  <div class="problem"></div>
  <div class="problem"></div>  
</div>
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll('.problems')` should be `querySelectorAll('.problem')`

Comment: Notice also, that you're invoking `getAddition` function when trying to attach `onload` listener to `window`. The said function doesn't return a function, hence the event won't be attached. Remove the parentheses at the end of the function name to make it a reference. And, don't rely element ids creating a global variable, always use a DOM method to get a reference to an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing should be your selector. `.problem` is what you have in your class.

Second thing, move the random number calculation inside the loop to get different problem.

```js
let getAddition = () => {
  let max = 10;
  
  let problems = document.querySelectorAll('.problem');
  
  problems.forEach((problem) => {
    const rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    const rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    const sum = rand1 + rand2;
    problem.textContent = `${rand1} + ${rand2} = ${sum}`;
  });
};

window.addEventListener('onload', getAddition());
newProblem.onclick = () => {
  getAddition();
};
```

```html
<button type="button" id="newProblem">New Problem</button>
<div class="container">
  <div class="problem"></div>
  <div class="problem"></div>
  <div class="problem"></div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Shri Hari L's solution can be shortened even further into:

```js
const problems=document.querySelectorAll('.problem');
window.onload=document.getElementById("newProblem").onclick=()=>{
  const max = 10;      
  problems.forEach((problem) => {
    const [rand1,rand2] = [1,2].map(_=>Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + 1);
    problem.textContent = `${rand1} + ${rand2} = ${rand1+rand2}`;
  });
};
```

```html
<button type="button" id="newProblem">New Problem</button>
<div class="container">
  <div class="problem"></div>
  <div class="problem"></div>
  <div class="problem"></div>  
</div>
```